# Is there an equivalent of move in webhdfs

Tags: hadoop, webhdfs

I would like to move one or more files from one path to another using webhdfs. I am using hadoop 1.3. Does such a REST call exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use [rename](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#RENAME) to "rename" the path to the file(s).